# window.history.pushState removing my part of URL

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, browser-history

I currently have this link:
`http://localhost:3000/A/B`

When I use `window.history.pushState(null, null , './pg-<%=params[:page]%>?pgsz=<%=params[:pgsz]%>')` it removes **B** part of my URL and then append the params to it.

And if I use `/` instead of `./` then it completely removes **/A/B**

How to just append my params to the end of my URL and keep changing only the end part.

Answer (score 0):

Try something along the lines of

`window.history.pushState(location.pathname + '?', null, './pg-<%=params[:page]%>?pgsz=<%=params[:pgsz]%>')`

In your above code it appends your params at the end of where it thinks the pathname ends so at the last `/`.